# Como adicionar Onclick em um fragment?

Tags: java, android, fragment

Estou tentando adicionar onclick no meu fragment, porém não estou conseguindo, onde está errado?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_more, container, false);

    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_conferma);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // do something
            } 
        }); 
    return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está retornando a View antes de configurar o Button e o listener dele. Nesta linha:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_more, container, false);
```

O certo é:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_more, container, false);

Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_conferma);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // do something
        } 
    }); 
return view;
```

Comment: Olá amigo, muito obrigado, funcionando!

Comment: Tranquilo @DanielPereira